# Files.readAllLines - what constitutes a "large" file?

Tags: java

The [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) javadoc states:

> "Note that this method is intended for simple cases where it is
>   convenient to read all lines in a single operation. It is not intended
>   for reading in large files."

What constitutes a large file in this context?  (I'm also curious about why it is not suggested for large files.  Is it the actual I/O that is the problem, or is it the size of memory used to store the results of the reading?)

Comment: I suggest using `lines()` as a Stream instead if the file is non-trivial. e.g. hundreds of MB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that this method reads **all** contents of the text file into the memory. If it is too large, you will simply receive `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Yep, to clarify: *large* is a relative term. Its amount can not be specified as it depends on the free memory on the particular machine.

Comment: Cheers, I've added clarification (thought it is obvious, but you are right, this should be explicitly empasized).

Comment: Sorry if it seemed petty. The answer just seemed incomplete when I read it.

Comment: No bother :)))) (4 smiles to allow comment be added)

Comment: It's the amount of free heap space which matters (also compressed strings might make a difference)

Comment: Your majesty, I don't think that such details matters for beginners who ask such kind of question...